# Ruby singleton methods with (class_eval, define_method) vs (instance_eval, define_method)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Metaprogramming in ruby is great because I constantly use it to emulate prototype based programming and quickly write prototype solutions to some problems to test their viability. So I would like to know if there is any essential difference between the following pieces of code:

```
(class << some_object; self; end).class_eval do
  define_method(:method_name) do ... method body ... end
end
```

and

```
(class << some_object; self; end).instance_eval do
  define_method(:method_name) do ... method body ... end
end
```

Both versions of the code define a singleton method and I haven't yet come up against anything that has forced me to choose the `(instance_eval, define_method)` combination over  the `(class_eval, define_method)` combination to define a singleton method and I'm wondering if there is some essential difference between the two.

Comment: Note that the best way to do the above is simply `define_singleton_method(:method_name) do ... end`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No difference for `define_method`. But there is a difference when you use `def`.

```
o = Object.new  

# class_eval example
class << o; self; end.class_eval { def test1;  :test1; end  }
o.test1 #=> test1

# instance_eval example
class << o; self; end.instance_eval { def test2; :test2; end }
o.test2 #=> NoMethodError
```

Why the difference in behaviour between `def` and `define_method` ? 
`define_method` is a method call and so operates on the `self` in the eval context. The `self` in both `instance_eval` and `class_eval` is the same - it is the  receiver (the eigenclass of o).

However `def` behaves differently, it does not operate on the `self` but instead on the [`default define`](http://yugui.jp/articles/846). In the case of `class_eval` the `default definee` is the same as `self` but for `instance_eval` it is instead the metaclass of `self`.

How do we access the `test2` method defined above? test2 must be an instance method defined on the metaclass of the eigenclass of o.

It is a class method on the eigenclass of o:

```
class << o; test2; end #=> :test2
```